# When trying to installing MySQL I got "unable to locate package mysql-server"

Tags: package-management, software-installation, mysql

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update`, then `apt-cache search mysql-server`

Comment: Then what is the next step?

Comment: What were the results of those command?

Comment: First command is still running

Comment: Both commands are over now.The result is as follows

Comment: user@user-SM:~$ apt-cache search mysql-server
mysql-server - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
mysql-server-5.5 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
mysql-server-core-5.5 - MySQL database server binaries

Comment: mariadb-server-5.5 - MariaDB database server binaries
mariadb-server-core-5.5 - MariaDB database core server files
mysql-server-5.6 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
mysql-server-core-5.6 - MySQL database server binaries
percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5 - Percona Server database server binaries
torrentflux - web based, feature-rich BitTorrent download manager

Comment: What is the next step?

Comment: Then i executed the command sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: @Videonauth I read all the answers to the duplicate question that you linked to. This question is not a duplicate of that question. It was also fake close voted for being unclear after the answer was accepted by the OP. This question is not unclear either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql-server is a metapackage depending on the latest version of mysql-server, so it doesn't need to be installed. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
```

Comment: I would argue there's probably no need to install aptitude just for this?

Comment: The reason why I included aptitude is to get more verbose error messages than apt provides in case the commands didn't work, however since the commands did work you're right, there was no need to install aptitude in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check whether the package you are searching for exists by opening the terminal and typing:

```
apt search <your package name>
```

Select the package you want to install by typing

```
sudo apt-get install <the package name you found after searching>
```

You can do this also in the synaptic package manager app.

Comment: How can i install mysql?